# More than one report in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi

It is possible to create more than one report in Power BI Desktop or you can only have one report with many pages?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create many reports as you want but you can't visualize only one concurrently from **Power BI Desktop**.

Each `.pbix` file is a Power BI report that could have one or more pages.

In summary, you can create several `.pbix` files but edit/visualize that one you have opened from Power BI Desktop.

Also note you can run several instances of Power BI Desktop at the same time each with a different report (`.pbix` file).